# Use cache docker image for gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-registry, gitlab-ce

I was wondering is it possible to use cached docker images in gitlab registry for gitlab-ci?
for example, I want to use `node:16.3.0-alpine` docker image, can I cache it in my gitlab registry and pull it from that and speed up my gitlab ci instead of pulling it from docker hub?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a corporate Gitlab instance where for some reason the Dependency Proxy feature has been disabled.  The other option you have is to create a new Docker image on your local machine, then push it into the Container Registry of your personal Gitlab project.

```bash
# First create a one-line Dockerfile containing "FROM node:16.3.0-alpine"
docker pull node:16.3.0-alpine
docker build . -t registry.example.com/group/project/image
docker login registry.example.com -u <username> -p <token>
docker push registry.example.com/group/project/image
```

where the image tag should be constructed based on the example given on your project's private Container Registry page.

Now in your CI job, you just change `image: node:16.3.0-alpine` to `image: registry.example.com/group/project/image`.  You may have to run the `docker login` command (using a deploy token for credentials, see Settings -> Repository) in the `before_script` section -- I think maybe newer versions of Gitlab will have the runner authenticate to the private Container Registry using system credentials, but that could vary depending on how it's configured.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, GitLab's [dependency proxy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/dependency_proxy/) features allow you to configure GitLab as a "[pull through cache](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/)". This is also beneficial for [working around rate limits](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/dependency_proxy/#docker-hub-rate-limits-and-the-dependency-proxy) of upstream sources like dockerhub.

It *should* be faster in most cases to use the dependency proxy, but not *necessarily* so. It's possible that dockerhub can be more performant than a small self-hosted server, for example. GitLab runners are also remote with respect to the registry and not *necessarily* any "closer" to the GitLab registry than any other registry over the internet. So, keep that in mind.

As a side note, the absolute fastest way to retrieve cached images is to self-host your GitLab runners and hold images directly on the host. That way, when jobs start, if the image already exists on the host, the job will start immediately because it does not need to pull the image (depending on your pull configuration). (that is, assuming you're using images in the `image:` declaration for your job)

Comment: Yes, I read that article about dependency proxy, but my problem is I want to cache docker images for my personal project(it's not in a group) and dependency proxy works only for groups